# Inline function in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to have an fully inlined function in Postgresql like IF-function in SQL Server? I want to have a peace of code to be easy used in queries, always inlined - how can I do this?

In my case I have some code and I want to use it easily, referencing it by name, like a function call, but always inlined. My code looks like:

```
Create Function "Permissions: Object Access Level For Person Operation"(_User uuid, _ObjectID uuid, _Operation uuid)
Returns int /*table ("Access Level" int)*/ as
$$
Select Coalesce
(
    (
        Select Max("Levels"."Access Level") "Access Level"
        From
        (
            Select
                "User Defined Fields: Values"."Object" "Person",
                Max("Permissions: Person Operations"."Access Level") "Access Level"
            From "Permissions: Person Operations"
            Inner Join "User Defined Fields: Values" On "User Defined Fields: Values"."Value" = "Permissions: Person Operations"."Field Value"
            Where "Permissions: Person Operations"."User" In (Select _User "User" Union Select "Entries"."Group" "User" From "Users: Group Entries" "Entries" Where "Entries"."User" = _User)
            And "Permissions: Person Operations"."Operation" = _Operation
            Group By "User Defined Fields: Values"."Object"
        ) "Levels"
        Where "Levels"."Person" = _ObjectID
    ),
    (
        Select "Level"."Access Level"
        From
        (
            Select Max("Operations"."Access Level") "Access Level"
            From "Permissions: Person Operations" "Operations"
            Where "Operations"."User" In (Select _User "User" Union Select "Entries"."Group" "User" From "Users: Group Entries" "Entries" Where "Entries"."User" = _User)
            And "Operations"."Operation" = _Operation
            And "Operations"."Field Value" Is Null
        ) "Level"
    ),
    (
        Select Max("Level"."Access Level") "Access Level"
        From
        (
            Select
                "User Defined Fields: Values"."Object" "Person",
                Max("Permissions: Persons"."Access Level") "Access Level"
            From "Permissions: Persons"
            Left Join "User Defined Fields: Values" On "User Defined Fields: Values"."Value" = "Permissions: Persons"."Field Value"
            Where "Permissions: Persons"."User" In (Select _User "User" Union Select "Entries"."Group" "User" From "Users: Group Entries" "Entries" Where "Entries"."User" = _User)
            Group By "User Defined Fields: Values"."Object"
        )   "Level"
        Where "Level"."Person" = _ObjectID
    ),
    (
        Select "Level"."Access Level"
        From 
        (
            Select Coalesce(Max("Permissions"."Access Level"),
                (Select "Default Access Level" From "Permissions: Subjects" Where "Object" = 'Person'), 0) "Access Level"
            From "Permissions"
            Inner Join "Permissions: Subjects" On "Permissions"."Subject" = "Permissions: Subjects"."id"
            Where "Permissions"."User" In (Select _User "User" Union Select "Entries"."Group" "User" From "Users: Group Entries" "Entries" Where "Entries"."User" = _User)
            And "Permissions: Subjects"."Object" = 'Person'
        ) "Level"
    )
) "Access Level";
$$
language SQL;
```

The usage of the function looks like this:

```
Select some_fields
From some_table
Where "Permissions: Object Access Level For Person Operation"(u, some_table.some_field, o) > 0
```

This query runs 5400ms. `EXPLAIN` shows a function call.

If I perform inlining by myself I get 80ms execution time:

```
Select some_fields
From some_table
Where Coalesce(...the rest of the code from my function here...) > 0
```

So, is there a way to do inlining automatically? Just by referencing a function?

Answer (score 0):

Inlining happens automatically if PostgreSQL thinks it is safe. The only way you can influence that is by writing the function so that it satisfies all [criteria](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions#Inlining_conditions_for_scalar_functions). In your case, the function fails because

> - the function body consists of a single, simple, `SELECT` expression
> - the body contains no aggregate or window function calls, no subqueries, no CTEs, no `FROM` clause or references to any table or table-like object, none of `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`, `DISTINCT`, `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`

If you cannot write the function like that, and you need the performance, you'll have to inline the function body by hand.

Comment: I think my funciton meets the "Inlining conditions for table functions". But If I convert this function to table function, it still does not inline. Why?

Comment: Even `STABLE` does not help when converting to a table function

Comment: Oops. I was wrong. `EXPLAIN` shows that table function is inlined, but it still runs 5400ms (like it was not inlined) instead of 80ms (when inlined manually).

Comment: Your function is no table function, (it doesn't return `SETOF something`). And it clearly fails the criteria.

Comment: I converted it to a table function and added `STABLE`. [Look at the modified code](https://pastebin.com/baqtmCb7).